# Code falling out from catch?

Tags: c#, sql-server, async-await, system.reactive, .net-4.6.2

I have a background task that is polling an SQL Server database every 200ms.

The code looks like this:

```
listener = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        topToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                        try
                        {
                            using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                            using (var command = new SqlCommand("marc.GetEvents", dbConnection))
                            {
                                await command.Connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromId", lastEventId);

                                using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(topToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
                                {
                                    int received = lastEventId;
                                    while (await reader.ReadAsync(topToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
                                    {
                                        /// do stuff...
                                    }
                                    lastEventId = received;
                                }
                            }
                            await Task.Delay(PollIntervalMilliseconds, topToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            if (ex is SqlException && topToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                            {
                                throw new OperationCanceledException("Operation cancelled by user", ex);
                            }

                            logger.Warn(ex, $"Exception on polling Codeks db. Waiting {delayOnSqlError}ms..."); // this is hit
                            _OnReaderEvent.OnError(ex);
                            await Task.Delay(delayOnSqlError, topToken).ConfigureAwait(false); // probably not executed
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    logger.Info("Listening task ended. Service is stopping?");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error(ex, "General exception"); // falling here
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Today I got a report about the fact that this task ended prematurely. According to the logs, the first `catch` set is hit and it is reporting an SQL Exception:

> 2018-08-01 17:42:08.6348|Warn|Exception on polling Codeks db. Waiting 5000ms... System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 53) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

But instead of delaying, it is falling out from the loop immedialtely to the outer `catch` with the very same exception.

> 2018-08-01 17:42:08.6488|Error|Jantar.CodeksConnector|General exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 53) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.<>c__DisplayClass189_0.b__0(Task t)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.InvokeRetryable[T](Func`2 moreFunc, TaskCompletionSource`1 source, IDisposable objectToDispose)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>      at Jantar.CodeksConnector.<b__18_0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Reactive.PlatformServices.ExceptionServicesImpl.Rethrow(Exception exception)
>      at System.Reactive.Stubs.<>c.<.cctor>b__2_1(Exception ex)
>      at System.Reactive.AnonymousSafeObserver`1.OnError(Exception error)
>      at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.SelectMany`2.*.OnError(Exception error)
>      at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Where`1._.OnError(Exception error)
>      at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.AsObservable`1.*.OnError(Exception error)
>      at System.Reactive.Observer`1.OnError(Exception error)
>      at System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject`1.OnError(Exception error)
>      at Jantar.CodeksConnector.<b__18_0>d.MoveNext()

I am out of ideas...

**[Update: 08.03]**

@sellotape pointed me to the right direction. According to the updated second log entry, the stacktrace makes it clear that the exception is rethrown by the `Subject<T>.onError(ex)` (which I have removed because it is a bug). It was a double bug, as there is no error subscriber. I was unaware that in this case the exception is rethrown, but only if there is any subscriber, and swallowed if there is none.

Comment: ... that's an interesting `while` statement...

Comment: why poll? why not query notifications? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server ... also you need to show stored proc

Comment: @Stefan, please explain, why.

Comment: @MitchWheat, that was a desigen decision a while ago. This is not the problem here.

Comment: sometimes design decisions need re-evaluating.... just saying....

Comment: Well, it's a bit out of scope but your code's behavior relies on throwing exceptions, while further on you use the `topToken.IsCancellationRequested` (which is preferable). Although this is open for debate; code in general shouldn't be controlled by throwing exception, especially if there is a property (IsCancellationRequested) which does the same without the hassle of exception handling.

Comment: True. But that is something very specific to SQL Server. And this code has counterparts for other RDBMS.

Comment: @Stefan would changig that resolve this issue? I doubt. It would only affect my `while`. All other async methods would still throw exception on cancellation.

Comment: The token was not cancelled at that moment. It was not affecting anything in the flow that caused this issue. Ok, I have eliminated that throw, but still no clue how this happened...

Comment: Another question: `await Task.Delay(delayOnSqlError, topToken).ConfigureAwait(false);` why the "ConfigureAwait(false)` ?

Comment: It seems that the "general" exception is thrown from the catch block

Comment: is it not possibly just that topToken was cancelled by the time that wait was called?

Comment: Possibly your `using` statement is accessing the object with a call to `Dispose`. Although that wouldn't explain the timing issue.

Comment: No, the topToken is the service level token. And the service continues to work, and everything else works also. Canceling the topToken would cause OperationCanceledException, which has it's own catch...

Comment: The only thing reused from the using context is the exception thrown. I would get ObjectDisposedException or something alike. But I am catching the same exception, as it would be rethrown. But only the OperationCanceledException is rethrown...

Comment: Put a breakpoint and cause an impossible to resolve deadlock in our dev db, then trace through the code and see what happens.

Comment: I was unable to cause such deadlock. But a timeout exception with an unterminated transaction. And one shutting down the SQL server. Both were handled by the code as expected.

Comment: Are those 2 log entries contiguous? 0.014s is relatively quite a long time inbetween. Does your log include the thread ID, and if so, is it the same for both entries?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, there is no thread id. There are two other entries inbetween, but they come from other part of the service.

Comment: @ZorgoZ - how about the stack trace then, for each of those 2 entries?  The logger is being passed the exception; usually the stack trace is included in the logged output.

Comment: @sellotape Well, you'r right, I would have to look closer. I had a `Subject<T>.onError(ex)` inside, which I spotted after the incident was reported, and removed right away, because it is cancelling al observers. The second exception stack trace makes it clear that it is rethrown by the `Observable`.

The interesting thing is, that when I tried to reproduce it, I have put that onError back. And still was not causing anything. I have tried to call onError multiple times in a LinqPad sketch, and nothing alike happened.

Comment: @ZorgoZ - after the edit that makes more sense now.  Prior to that, there were no possible code paths that could have resulted in the outer catch catching a `SqlException`.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a direct answer to your question, you've tagged it as "System.Reactive" so I thought I might show you (roughly) what an Rx solution to your code looks like. Keep in mind that I couldn't accurately provide code for `/// do stuff...` so I made it up.

Here's the Rx:

```
IObservable<string> query =
    from t in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(PollIntervalMilliseconds))
    from x in Observable.Using(
        () => new SqlConnection(ConnectionString),
        dbConnection =>
            Observable.Using(
                () =>
                {
                    var c = new SqlCommand("marc.GetEvents", dbConnection);
                    c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromId", lastEventId);
                    return c;
                },
                command =>
                    from o in Observable.FromAsync(() => command.Connection.OpenAsync())
                    from reader in Observable.FromAsync(() => command.ExecuteReaderAsync(topToken))
                    let received = lastEventId
                    from r in Observable.FromAsync(() => reader.ReadAsync(topToken))
                    select reader.GetFieldValue<string>(0)))
    select x;
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Thank you.